# Using SpVoice in c++ windows

Tags: c++, mfc, text-to-speech

I'd like to add text to speech to my app and this API looks nice and simple:

```
SpVoice spVoice = new SpVoice();
spVoice.Speak("Hello World", SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFPurgeBeforeSpeak);
```

the problem is i can't figure out how to compiler this. Is there a package i have to download first? is there a header and a .lib or .dll i can link with?

i have a basic, vanilla c++ MFC application (no 'using' or 'import' whatever they are, just old fashioned #include). i hope someone can help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hans Passant pointed out, you do need to initialize COM using either CoInitialize (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or CoInitializeEx (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695279%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then unitialize COM using CoUninitialize (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688715%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in order to get this to work.

The following is a complete sample.

```
// Including sdkddkver.h defines the highest available Windows platform.
#include <sdkddkver.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sapi.h>

#include <string>

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    HRESULT hr = ::CoInitialize(nullptr);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    std::wstring text;
    if (1 == argc)
    {
        text = L"Hello World! It truly is a wonderful day to be alive.";
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
        {
            text += argv[i];
            if (i + 1 < argc)
            {
                text += L" ";
            }
        }
    }
    CComPtr<ISpVoice> cpVoice;
    // Create a SAPI voice
    hr = cpVoice.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpVoice);
    // set the output to the default audio device
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = cpVoice->SetOutput(NULL, TRUE);
    }
    // Speak the text
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = cpVoice->Speak(text.c_str(), SPF_PURGEBEFORESPEAK, NULL);
    }
    ::CoUninitialize();
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: awesome, that works, thanks. actually, i didn't need to add the library for some reason.

Comment: this is so useful for debugging real time programs. i'm writing an autopilot for a flight simulator and there is too much to keep track of watching for TRACE outputs and the plane. this is a really fantastic tool, and so easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like C# to me and not C++. In order to do it in C++ you need to include sapi.h and link with sapi.lib. Then you can do the following.

```
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
CComPtr<ISpVoice> cpVoice;

// Create a SAPI voice
hr = cpVoice.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpVoice);
// set the output to the default audio device
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = cpVoice->SetOutput( NULL, TRUE );
}
// Speak the text
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = cpVoice->Speak(L"Hello World",  SPF_PURGEBEFORESPEAK, NULL);
}
```

See the following resource for more information.

**Simple TTS Guide SAPI 5.4:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee431810%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: You ought to post a small note to remind the OP that initializing COM is required to make this code work.  Or leave it up to this comment :)